# How to selectively position elements with respect to other elements in css

Tags: html, css

Hi I am wondering how to align/position html elements specifically with respect to other elements using CSS. Here is a fiddle http://bit.ly/1tbOHEY where in I wish to show the sidebar element 1 to get aligned with the div having `id="alignwithme1"` and the sidebar element 2 to get aligned with div having `id="alignwithme2"`, which will result in something like the below image.
[image]

Is it possible to do selective positioning with respect to other html elements using CSS? A solution will be very helpful. Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: how about using grids like bootstrap / purecss. This can make your layout easier

Comment: Hmm using grids is a good idea @bwaaaaaa ,thanks I will try making some own custom grids for this one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing. **CSS Selectors cannot traverse backwards**. So, there is no way the children of two separate elements be styled relatively using css alone, unless one of the element is a child of the other element.

If you want a full CSS method and the height of #usual1 is unknown, this might be your only option:

**HTML**

```
<div id='header'>Header</div>
<div id="mainpost">
    <div id="alignwithme1">Align with Me 1
        <div id="se1">Sidebar element 1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="usual1"></div>
    <div id="alignwithme2">Align with Me 2
        <div id="se2">sidebar element 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

& **CSS**

```
#header{width:auto; height:25px; font-size:15px; text-align:center;background:black; color:white;}
#mainpost{width:50%; height:auto; background:yellow; color:black;padding:12px;float:left;}
#usual1{width:160px;height:145px;background:black;color:white;margin:10px;}
#alignwithme1{width:auto; height:50px;background:black;color:white;margin:10px;text-align:center;padding:4px;}
#alignwithme2{width:auto; height:50px;background:black;color:white;margin:10px;text-align:center;padding:4px;}
#sidebar{width:40%; height:auto;float:right;}
#se1{width:auto;height:35px;color:black;background:#44accf;padding:9px;text-align:center;margin:10px;}
#se2{width:auto;height:35px;color:black;background: #44accf;padding:9px;text-align:center;margin:10px;}

#alignwithme1,
#alignwithme2{
    position: relative;
}
#se1,
#se2{
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 110%;
}
```

***This is the method used to position submenus in vertical menus.***

Otherwise, you will have to find out the top-offset using JS and use it to position your element. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes we can do that but the problem here is they are two separate content containers, one is post and the other is sidebar as a result we can't really nest the divs together otherwise this would have worked perfectly, I wished to show the specific widget contents in the sidebar aligned specifically with certain post element divs but since they cannot be nested together for being different containers altogether I wanted to learn how to do this specifically with respect to id's.

Comment: CSS Selectors cannot traverse backwards. So, there is no way the children of two separate elements be styled relatively using css alone, unless one of the element is a child of the other element.

Comment: Hmm totally makes sense ! So can we do it any other way ? What about Jquery to manipulate the dom

Comment: Yup, that is possible.

Comment: This would be the equation to calculate the offset between Sidebar element 1 and 2:

Comment: margin-top(se2) = (height(alignwithme1)+margin-bottom(alignwithme1)+height(usual1)+margin-top(usual1)+margin-bottom(usual1)+margin-top(alignwithme2)) - height(se1)

Comment: I am sorry for that. But I'm a teacher as well. So that's the max you're going to get from me. Try to get the same from jQuery by yourself or you will escape only for now.

Comment: Oooh that's great I have got the whole idea on how am going to do this. Basically I will use script to calculate the distance between my  `alignwithme 1` & `2` div elements and then serve the same distance between my sidebar div elements. :) Thanks @BlackPanther